# Background image only covering text

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is the following: Have a header on top of the page with links and a logo (that’s working). Then below I would like to have an image that takes up the rest of the screen. Right now, the image is only behind the text that I have there.

Here is the HTML that I’m using for that section:

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.main{
    background-image:url('background1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}

.main h1{
    color:#ffffff;
}

.main h3{
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background image only covers the background of the element to which it belongs. Your div `main` is only as big as the content it contains. The background gets cut off because the div is only so big. Try setting the background as the background of `body`:

```
body {
    background-image:url('background1.jpg');
}
```

This should cover the whole page. [**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNxBr/)

To get a feel for what I mean in my statement above, add a bunch of `<br/>`s to `.main` and watch how the background image expands with the size of the div.

To take advantage of this, you can adjust the height of the div. To get it to fill 100% of the screen without adding content, you need to add this:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.main {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle using 100% heights**](http://jsfiddle.net/nNxBr/1/)

Comment: Thank you, that makes a ton of sense. I appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Comment: @user3622465 No problem, glad I could help. If this solved your problem, please check this answer as the correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the height of .main to 100%. You may also need to set the height of body to 100%.

Try:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
}
```